# The blogger static page is not displaying content fully

Tags: blogger, blogspot, static-pages

The privacy policy of my static page - http://www.jobzal.com/p/privacy-policy.html contains around 1674 words.

The problem is the content is not displaying fully. Instead, it is showing only the snippet with 43 words that actually appears similar to the home page and the index pages.

I think few edits should be made on the main HTML/theme page.

How to diagnose this problem?

Comment: The problem is that your blog shows static page posts like index page posts. Add your blog posts widget code.

Comment: I've added the blog post codes below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show post body instead of post snippet on static pages so according to your code below search for this :

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<data:post.body/>
<b:else/>
```

And replace it with :

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;item&quot;,&quot;static_page&quot;}'>
<data:post.body/>
<b:else/>
```

Comment: After changing the code as you've said. The static page post is appearing fully. But the content is displayed in sidebar and beyond the body width.

Comment: To solve that go to your page > edit > html  search for `width: 1333px;` and remove it.

Comment: I'm searching the html page for 1/2 hour. I can't find the code "width: 1333px;"

Comment: Ok, not in your xml, go to your page where you write the text.

Comment: OMG, I was searching in xml - theme page. Now I've removed "width: 1333px;" from the editor page and its working fine. Awesome! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='post-header'>
            <div class='post-header-line-1'/>
          </div>

          <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id' itemprop='articleBody'>
            <data:post.body/>
            <div style='clear: both;'/> <!-- clear for photos floats -->
          </div>
<div id='related-posts'> <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'> </b:if> <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'> <script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=related_results_labels&amp;max-results=6&quot;' type='text/javascript'/></b:if></b:loop>
<script type='text/javascript'> var maxresults=5; removeRelatedDuplicates(); printRelatedLabels(&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;); </script>
</div>
<div class='post-footer'>
            <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-1'>
              <span class='post-author vcard'>
                <b:if cond='data:top.showAuthor'>
                  <b:if cond='data:post.authorProfileUrl'>
                    <span class='fn' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
                      <meta expr:content='data:post.authorProfileUrl' itemprop='url'/>
                      <a expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' rel='author' title='author profile'>
                        <span itemprop='name'><data:post.author/></span>
                      </a>
                    </span>
                  <b:else/>
                    <span class='fn' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
                      <span itemprop='name'><data:post.author/></span>
                    </span>
                  </b:if>
                </b:if>
              </span>

              <span class='post-timestamp'>
                <b:if cond='data:top.showTimestamp'>
                  <data:top.timestampLabel/>
                  <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
                    <meta expr:content='data:post.url.canonical' itemprop='url'/>
                    <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601' itemprop='datePublished'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
                  </b:if>
                </b:if>
              </span>
              <span class='post-comment-link'>
                <b:include cond='data:blog.pageType not in {&quot;item&quot;,&quot;static_page&quot;}                                  and data:post.allowComments' data='post' name='comment_count_picker'/>
              </span>
            </div>

            <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-2'>
              <b:if cond='data:top.showMobileShare'>
                <div class='mobile-link-button goog-inline-block' id='mobile-share-button'>
                  <a href='javascript:void(0);'><data:shareMsg/></a>
                </div>
              </b:if>
              <b:if cond='data:top.showDummy'>
                <div class='goog-inline-block dummy-container'><data:post.dummyTag/></div>
              </b:if>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <b:include cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}' data='post' name='comment_picker'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='nextprev'>
  <div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'>
    <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
      <span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><data:newerPageTitle/></a>
      </span>
    </b:if>

    <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
      <span id='blog-pager-older-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><data:olderPageTitle/></a>
      </span>
    </b:if>

    <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:homeMsg/></a>

    <b:if cond='data:mobileLinkUrl'>
      <div class='blog-mobile-link'>
        <a expr:href='data:mobileLinkUrl'><data:mobileLinkMsg/></a>
      </div>
    </b:if>

  </div>
  <div class='clear'/>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='post' var='post'>
  <div class='post hentry uncustomized-post-template' itemprop='blogPost' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
      <meta expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl' itemprop='image_url'/>
    </b:if>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.blogId' itemprop='blogId'/>
    <meta expr:content='data:post.id' itemprop='postId'/>

    <a expr:name='data:post.id'/>
    <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
      <h1 class='post-title entry-title' itemprop='name'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.link or (data:post.url and data:blog.url != data:post.url)'>
        <a expr:href='data:post.link ? data:post.link : data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
      <b:else/>
        <data:post.title/>
      </b:if>
      </h1>
    </b:if>
    <div class='post-header'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<span class='post-author vcard'>
        <b:if cond='data:top.showAuthor'>
          <data:top.authorLabel/>
            <b:if cond='data:post.authorProfileUrl'>
              <span class='fn' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
                <meta expr:content='data:post.authorProfileUrl' itemprop='url'/>
                <a class='g-profile' expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' rel='author' title='author profile'>
                  <span itemprop='name'><data:post.author/></span>
                </a>
              </span>
            <b:else/>
              <span class='fn' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
                <span itemprop='name'><data:post.author/></span>
              </span>
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </span>
<span class='post-comment-link' style='Float:right;'>
<a class='comment-link' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 0'>
Be the first to comment!
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 1'>
<data:post.numComments/>
Comment so far
<b:else/>
<data:post.numComments/>
Comments so far
</b:if>
</b:if>
</a>
</span>
<span class='post-timestamp' style='display:none;'>
        <b:if cond='data:top.showTimestamp'>
          <data:top.timestampLabel/>
          <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
            <meta expr:content='data:post.url.canonical' itemprop='url'/>
            <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601' itemprop='datePublished'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </span>
<br/><br/>
</b:if>
    <div class='post-header-line-1'/>
    </div>
    <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id' expr:itemprop='(data:blog.metaDescription ? &quot;&quot; : &quot;description &quot;) + &quot;articleBody&quot;'>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<data:post.body/>
<b:else/>
<div class='swtSummary' expr:id='&quot;swtExcerpt-&quot; + data:post.id'><data:post.body/></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
swtAutoSummay(&quot;swtExcerpt-<data:post.id/>&quot;);
</script>
<div class='jump-link'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'><data:post.jumpText/></a>
</div>
</b:if>
      <div class='div-separate' style='clear: both;'/> <!-- clear for photos floats -->
    </div>

    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div class='post-footer'>
    <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-1'>
      <span class='post-comment-link'>
        <b:include cond='data:blog.pageType not in {&quot;item&quot;,&quot;static_page&quot;}                          and data:post.allowComments' data='post' name='comment_count_picker'/>
      </span>

       <!-- backlinks -->
       <span class='post-backlinks post-comment-link'>
         <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType not in {&quot;item&quot;,&quot;static_page&quot;}                      and data:post.showBacklinks'>
           <a class='comment-link' expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#links&quot;'><data:top.backlinkLabel/></a>
         </b:if>
       </span>

      <span class='post-icons'>
        <!-- email post links -->
        <b:if cond='data:post.emailPostUrl'>
          <span class='item-action'>
          <a expr:href='data:post.emailPostUrl' expr:title='data:top.emailPostMsg'>
            <img alt='' class='icon-action' height='13' src='https://resources.blogblog.com/img/icon18_email.gif' width='18'/>
          </a>
          </span>
        </b:if>

        <!-- quickedit pencil -->
        <b:include data='post' name='postQuickEdit'/>
      </span>

      </div>

      <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-3'>
      <span class='post-location'>
        <b:if cond='data:top.showLocation and data:post.location'>
          <data:postLocationLabel/>
          <a expr:href='data:post.location.mapsUrl' target='_blank'><data:post.location.name/></a>
        </b:if>
      </span>
      </div>
      <b:if cond='data:post.authorAboutMe'>
        <div class='author-profile' itemprop='author' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Person'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.authorPhoto.url'>
            <img expr:src='data:post.authorPhoto.url' itemprop='image' width='50px'/>
          </b:if>
          <div>
            <a class='g-profile' expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' itemprop='url' rel='author' title='author profile'>
              <span itemprop='name'><data:post.author/></span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <span itemprop='description'><data:post.authorMe/></span>
        </div>
      </b:if>
    </div>
<div id='related-posts'> <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'> </b:if> <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'> <script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=related_results_labels&amp;max-results=6&quot;' type='text/javascript'/></b:if></b:loop>
<script type='text/javascript'> var maxresults=5; removeRelatedDuplicates(); printRelatedLabels(&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;); </script></div>
<div id='sharethis'>
<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'/>
<span class='st_googleplus_hcount' displayText='Google +'/>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'/>
<span class='st_linkedin_hcount' displayText='LinkedIn'/>
<span class='st_pinterest_hcount' displayText='Pinterest'/>
<span class='st_reddit_hcount' displayText='Reddit'/>
</div>
</b:if>
</div>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='postQuickEdit' var='post'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.editUrl'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:post.adminClass'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.editUrl' expr:title='data:top.editPostMsg'>
        <img alt='' class='icon-action' height='18' src='https://resources.blogblog.com/img/icon18_edit_allbkg.gif' width='18'/>
      </a>
    </span>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='shareButtons' var='post'>
  <b:if cond='data:top.showEmailButton'><a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-email' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=email&quot;' expr:title='data:top.emailThisMsg' target='_blank'><span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.emailThisMsg/></span></a></b:if><b:if cond='data:top.showBlogThisButton'><a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-blog' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=blog&quot;' expr:onclick='&quot;window.open(this.href, \&quot;_blank\&quot;, \&quot;height=270,width=475\&quot;); return false;&quot;' expr:title='data:top.blogThisMsg' target='_blank'><span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.blogThisMsg/></span></a></b:if><b:if cond='data:top.showTwitterButton'><a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-twitter' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=twitter&quot;' expr:title='data:top.shareToTwitterMsg' target='_blank'><span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.shareToTwitterMsg/></span></a></b:if><b:if cond='data:top.showFacebookButton'><a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-facebook' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=facebook&quot;' expr:onclick='&quot;window.open(this.href, \&quot;_blank\&quot;, \&quot;height=430,width=640\&quot;); return false;&quot;' expr:title='data:top.shareToFacebookMsg' target='_blank'><span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.shareToFacebookMsg/></span></a></b:if><b:if cond='data:top.showPinterestButton'><a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-pinterest' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=pinterest&quot;' expr:title='data:top.shareToPinterestMsg' target='_blank'><span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.shareToPinterestMsg/></span></a></b:if><b:if cond='data:top.showPlusOne'><div class='goog-inline-block google-plus-share-container'><data:post.googlePlusShareTag/></div></b:if>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='status-message'>
  <b:if cond='data:navMessage'>
  <div class='status-msg-wrap'>
    <div class='status-msg-body'>
      <data:navMessage/>
    </div>
    <div class='status-msg-border'>
      <div class='status-msg-bg'>
        <div class='status-msg-hidden'><data:navMessage/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='clear: both;'/>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='threaded-comment-form' var='post'>
  <div class='comment-form'>
    <a name='comment-form'/>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' expr:height='data:cmtIframeInitialHeight' frameborder='0' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' style='display: none' width='100%'/>
    <b:else/>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' expr:height='data:cmtIframeInitialHeight' frameborder='0' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' width='100%'/>
    </b:if>
    <data:post.cmtfpIframe/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      BLOG_CMT_createIframe(&#39;<data:post.appRpcRelayPath/>&#39;);
    </script>
  </div>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='threaded_comment_js' var='post'>
  <script async='async' expr:src='data:post.commentSrc' type='text/javascript'/>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
      var items = <data:post.commentJso/>;
      var msgs = <data:post.commentMsgs/>;
      var config = <data:post.commentConfig/>;

// <![CDATA[
      var cursor = null;
      if (items && items.length > 0) {
        cursor = parseInt(items[items.length - 1].timestamp) + 1;
      }

      var bodyFromEntry = function(entry) {
        if (entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
          for (var k in entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
            if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.contentRemoved') {
              return '<span class="deleted-comment">' + entry.content.$t + '</span>';
            }
          }
        }
        return entry.content.$t;
      }

      var parse = function(data) {
        cursor = null;
        var comments = [];
        if (data && data.feed && data.feed.entry) {
          for (var i = 0, entry; entry = data.feed.entry[i]; i++) {
            var comment = {};
            // comment ID, parsed out of the original id format
            var id = /blog-(\d+).post-(\d+)/.exec(entry.id.$t);
            comment.id = id ? id[2] : null;
            comment.body = bodyFromEntry(entry);
            comment.timestamp = Date.parse(entry.published.$t) + '';
            if (entry.author && entry.author.constructor === Array) {
              var auth = entry.author[0];
              if (auth) {
                comment.author = {
                  name: (auth.name ? auth.name.$t : undefined),
                  profileUrl: (auth.uri ? auth.uri.$t : undefined),
                  avatarUrl: (auth.gd$image ? auth.gd$image.src : undefined)
                };
              }
            }
            if (entry.link) {
              if (entry.link[2]) {
                comment.link = comment.permalink = entry.link[2].href;
              }
              if (entry.link[3]) {
                var pid = /.*comments\/default\/(\d+)\?.*/.exec(entry.link[3].href);
                if (pid && pid[1]) {
                  comment.parentId = pid[1];
                }
              }
            }
            comment.deleteclass = 'item-control blog-admin';
            if (entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
              for (var k in entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
                if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.itemClass') {
                  comment.deleteclass += ' ' + entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].value;
                } else if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.displayTime') {
                  comment.displayTime = entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].value;
                }
              }
            }
            comments.push(comment);
          }
        }
        return comments;
      };

      var paginator = function(callback) {
        if (hasMore()) {
          var url = config.feed + '?alt=json&v=2&orderby=published&reverse=false&max-results=50';
          if (cursor) {
            url += '&published-min=' + new Date(cursor).toISOString();
          }
          window.bloggercomments = function(data) {
            var parsed = parse(data);
            cursor = parsed.length < 50 ? null
                : parseInt(parsed[parsed.length - 1].timestamp) + 1
            callback(parsed);
            window.bloggercomments = null;
          }
          url += '&callback=bloggercomments';
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = url;
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
      };
      var hasMore = function() {
        return !!cursor;
      };
      var getMeta = function(key, comment) {
        if ('iswriter' == key) {
          var matches = !!comment.author
              && comment.author.name == config.authorName
              && comment.author.profileUrl == config.authorUrl;
          return matches ? 'true' : '';
        } else if ('deletelink' == key) {
          return config.baseUri + '/delete-comment.g?blogID='
               + config.blogId + '&postID=' + comment.id;
        } else if ('deleteclass' == key) {
          return comment.deleteclass;
        }
        return '';
      };

      var replybox = null;
      var replyUrlParts = null;
      var replyParent = undefined;

      var onReply = function(commentId, domId) {
        if (replybox == null) {
          // lazily cache replybox, and adjust to suit this style:
          replybox = document.getElementById('comment-editor');
          if (replybox != null) {
            replybox.height = '250px';
            replybox.style.display = 'block';
            replyUrlParts = replybox.src.split('#');
          }
        }
        if (replybox && (commentId !== replyParent)) {
          replybox.src = '';
          document.getElementById(domId).insertBefore(replybox, null);
          replybox.src = replyUrlParts[0]
              + (commentId ? '&parentID=' + commentId : '')
              + '#' + replyUrlParts[1];
          replyParent = commentId;
        }
      };

      var hash = (window.location.hash || '#').substring(1);
      var startThread, targetComment;
      if (/^comment-form_/.test(hash)) {
        startThread = hash.substring('comment-form_'.length);
      } else if (/^c[0-9]+$/.test(hash)) {
        targetComment = hash.substring(1);
      }

      // Configure commenting API:
      var configJso = {
        'maxDepth': config.maxThreadDepth
      };
      var provider = {
        'id': config.postId,
        'data': items,
        'loadNext': paginator,
        'hasMore': hasMore,
        'getMeta': getMeta,
        'onReply': onReply,
        'rendered': true,
        'initComment': targetComment,
        'initReplyThread': startThread,
        'config': configJso,
        'messages': msgs
      };

      var render = function() {
        if (window.goog && window.goog.comments) {
          var holder = document.getElementById('comment-holder');
          window.goog.comments.render(holder, provider);
        }
      };

      // render now, or queue to render when library loads:
      if (window.goog && window.goog.comments) {
        render();
      } else {
        window.goog = window.goog || {};
        window.goog.comments = window.goog.comments || {};
        window.goog.comments.loadQueue = window.goog.comments.loadQueue || [];
        window.goog.comments.loadQueue.push(render);
      }
    })();
// ]]>
  </script>
</b:includable>
              <b:includable id='threaded_comments' var='post'>
  <div class='comments' id='comments'>
    <a name='comments'/>
    <h4><data:post.commentLabelFull/>:</h4>

    <div class='comments-content'>
      <b:include cond='data:post.embedCommentForm' data='post' name='threaded_comment_js'/>
      <div id='comment-holder'>
         <data:post.commentHtml/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class='comment-footer'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.allowNewComments'>
        <b:include data='post' name='threaded-comment-form'/>
      <b:else/>
        <data:post.noNewCommentsText/>
      </b:if>
    </p>

    <b:if cond='data:showCmtPopup'>
      <div id='comment-popup'>
        <iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' id='comment-actions' name='comment-actions' scrolling='no'>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div id='backlinks-container'>
    <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_backlinks-container&quot;'>
      <b:include cond='data:post.showBacklinks' data='post' name='backlinks'/>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
            </b:widget>
          </b:section>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class='column-left-outer'>
        <div class='column-left-inner'>
          <aside>
          <macro:include id='main-column-left-sections' name='sections'>
            <macro:param default='0' name='num'/>
            <macro:param default='sidebar-left' name='idPrefix'/>
            <macro:param default='sidebar' name='class'/>
            <macro:param default='true' name='includeBottom'/>
          </macro:include>
          </aside>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class='column-right-outer'>
        <div class='column-right-inner'>
          <aside>
          <macro:include id='main-column-right-sections' name='sections'>
            <macro:param default='2' name='num'/>
            <macro:param default='sidebar-right' name='idPrefix'/>
            <macro:param default='sidebar' name='class'/>
            <macro:param default='true' name='includeBottom'/>
          </macro:include>
          </aside>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div style='clear: both'/>
      <!-- columns -->
      </div>

    <!-- main -->
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='main-cap-bottom cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
    <div class='footer-outer'>
    <div class='footer-cap-top cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left footer-fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right footer-fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='region-inner footer-inner'>
      <macro:include id='footer-sections' name='sections'>
        <macro:param default='2' name='num'/>
        <macro:param default='footer' name='idPrefix'/>
        <macro:param default='foot' name='class'/>
        <macro:param default='false' name='includeBottom'/>
      </macro:include>
      <!-- outside of the include in order to lock Attribution widget -->
      <b:section class='foot' id='footer-3' name='Footer' showaddelement='yes'/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer-cap-bottom cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile == &quot;false&quot;'>
<div class='Credits'><a href=''>Disclaimer</a> | <a href='http://www.jobzal.com/p/privacy-policy.html'>Privacy Policy</a> | <a href=''>Contact</a> | <a href=''>Terms And Conditions</a> | <a href=''>Sitemap</a> | <a href=''>Adchoices</a> | &#169; Copyright 2016
<a href='#' id='top'>&#8679; Top</a>
</div>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile == &quot;true&quot;'>
<div class='Credits'><a href=''>Disclaimer</a> | <a href=''>Privacy Policy</a> | <a href=''>Contact</a> | <a href=''>Sitemap</a> | <a href=''>Adchoices</a> | &#169; Copyright 2016
<a href='#' id='top'>&#8679; Top</a></div>
</b:if>
    </footer>

  <!-- content -->
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class='content-cap-bottom cap-bottom'>
    <div class='cap-left'/>
    <div class='cap-right'/>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(&#39;loading&#39;, &#39;&#39;);
      }, 10);
  </script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/101Helper/docs/master/jsinstallizer.js'/>
<style>.sticker {position:fixed; top:-15px; z-index:99;}</style>
<script>
```